# Safe way to store primary key generator outside of database?

Tags: sql, filesystems, primary-key

We have an application which stores its data in SQL Server.  Each table has a bigint primary key.  We used to generate these exclusively on demand, i.e. when you go to insert a new row, you first make a call to generate the next ID, and then you do the insert.

We added support to run in offline mode: if your connection is down (or SQL Server is down), it saves the data to a local file until you go back online, and then syncs everything you've done since then.

This required being able to generate IDs on the client side.  Instead of asking SQL for the next 1 ID, it now asks for the next hundred or thousand or 10,000 IDs, and then stores the range locally, so it doesn't have to ask for more until those 10,000 run out.  It would actually get them in smaller chunks, so when 5000 run out, it still has a buffer of 5000, and it can ask for 5000 more.

The problem is, as soon as this went live, we started getting reports of primary key violations.  We stored the data in the Windows registry, in HKEY_CURRENT_USER (the only place in the registry a user is guaranteed to be able to write to).  So after some research, we discovered that HKEY_CURRENT_USER is part of the roaming profile, so it's possible the IDs could get overwritten with an old version.  Especially if the user logs into multiple computers on the network simultaneously.

So we re-wrote the part that generates IDs to read/write a file from the user's "Local Settings" directory.  Surely that shouldn't get overwritten by an old version.  But even now, I still see occasional primary key violations.  The only thing we can do in that case is delete any keys in the file, kick the user out of the application, and don't let them back in until they get new ID ranges.

But if "Local Settings" isn't safe, what would be?  Is there anywhere you can store a persistent value on a computer which is guaranteed not to be rolled back to an old version?  Can anyone explain why "Local Settings" does not meet this criteria?

I've done some consideration of a GUID like solution, but that has problems on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have to use the same key when you persist the data locally that you use when you sync with the database?

I would be sorely tempted to use a GUID when you persist the data locally and then generate the real key when you're actually writing the data to the database.  Or persist the data locally starting with a value of 1 and then generate real keys when you actually write the data to the database.

Comment: this is exactly it.  let a centralized sequence peform its job, and just map to the new ids when synchronizing.

Comment: The ID is used as a foreign key in other tables, internally in objects, and in database and non-database storage of external applications.  It might be possible to deal with a placeholder for some of that, but it would multiply code complexity, and some of it just plain needs the ID immediately, not after the item gets written to the database.

Comment: I guess this is the most useful answer I'll get.  Even though it's not quite practical to use, I'll accept it just to close the question.

Answer (score 5):

in distributed environment as yours, your best bet is using GUID

Comment: +1 Absolutely. GUID primary keys do have issues of their own, but GUID problems are trivial compared to the problems you'll have trying to implement your own home-grown distributed, auto-incremented key system.

Comment: Ignoring the part about continuity of IDs being nice to deal with on the occasions when I actually have to run queries, there are still other issues, such as having a limit of 15 character decimal representation (due to an export format), years and years of old data, and the way the changes that would cascade to other applications... I could try to make my own GUID format, but practical considerations mean I would have something like 32 actual bits to work with, which is nowhere near enough for something as wasteful of bits as a GUID generator.

Comment: if you only have 32 bits to work with, you have much bigger problems than globally unique ID, I think you should consider some restructuring and/or schema change

Answer (score 0):

Setup an IDENTITY (http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/identity-columns/) on the bigint primary key so that SQL Server generates the values automatically.

When your application is offline, you keep the pending changes local.  When it comes back online, you send your updates (including new records) and SQL Server would INSERT them and automatically assign a primary key since you have the IDENTITY setup.

If you need to know what key value was generated/used after an insert you can utilize the @@IDENTITY property (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933167%28v=sql.80%29.aspx)

Comment: this is actually on the right track.  it is similar to @Justin Cave's answer - although a bit more ambiguous in how you would do the mapping.